# error 404 when try to make oauth in pulsar stream native cluster

Tags: apache-pulsar, python-pulsar

Hello I am triying to connect to apache pulsar cluster using stream native, I don't have problems with token oauth, but when I try to make Oauth I always get malformed responde or 404 I am using curl and python client, and following their instructions,like this.

```
params = '''
{
    "issuer_url": "https://auth.streamnative.cloud/",
    "private_key": test.json",
    "audience": "urn:sn:pulsar:test:test"
}
'''

pulsar_client = pulsar.Client(
    PULSAR_URL,
    authentication=AuthenticationOauth2(params)
)
```

and the error is the following:

```
AuthOauth2:223 | Response failed for getting the well-known configuration https://auth.streamnative.cloud/. response Code 404
```

But the params and url I get from https://console.streamnative.cloud/test/test/clients, but nothing.

Any Idea about how can I connect to the cluster with the oauth?

**EDIT**

With client the credentials works, looks like a bug in python package of pulsar 2.9.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the full path to the private key.  make sure it has permissions.

also make sure your audience is correct

what is pulsar URL format?

```
pulsar+ssl://sn-myinstance.mycluster.snio.cloud:6651
```

I have an example python app here

https://github.com/tspannhw/FLiP-Pi-BreakoutGarden/blob/c056b0eccc7ad18f8b18740bb30c224467991310/consume.sh

```
client = pulsar.Client(args.service_url, authentication=AuthenticationOauth2(args.auth_params))
```

https://docs.streamnative.io/cloud/stable/connect/client/connect-python

https://github.com/streamnative/examples/blob/master/cloud/README.md

Also make sure you gave the userid associated with your key permissions.

If that doesn't work, chat with me on the Pulsar slack.

Comment: Hello, the pulsar url, is correct, the path, I tried with absolute path and with relative path  but both get the same error 404, and audience is the audience that streamnative show in the connection secions, urn:sn:pulsar:user:instace